# How to know context of the ContextMenu in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, contextmenu

Context menu, is, by definition, a menu, called against some context.

Unfortunately, I can't see any means to obtain this context in [`ContextMenu`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/ContextMenu.html). Is this really impossible?

Comment: "_called against some context._" meaning a node?  or a lil elabo will be great

Answer (score 0):

*from my current understanding of what you want, you can not do that really*

but try these

```
ContextMenu.getOwnerNode();
ContextMenu.getOwnerWidnow();
```

aside from that it has a userData so i guess, you could pass your "context" there